# Find visible children in a hidden parent

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way, with jQuery, to get all "visible" elements that are contained within a "hidden" container without making the container itself visible?

For instance...

```
<div id="container" style="display:none">
  <div>Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Hidden</div>
  <div>Another Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Another Hidden</div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do...

```
$("#container div:visible")  or  $("#container div").filter(":visible")
```

.. and they would return the 1st and 3rd `<div>` children.

However, because `#container` is itself hidden, it doesn't return anything.

Is this possible without making `#container` visible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. `display:none` affects the element and all its descendants, they do not even get rendered. And what does not get rendered, can not be visible or invisible to begin with.

Comment: Agreed with @CBroe  . BTW you can try with `style="visibility:hidden"`

Comment: OK, @CBroe, that makes sense.  Would it make sense, therefore, to look at the style of the child, instead of using `:visible`

Comment: @AlivetoDie - problem with `visibility:hidden` is that it keeps the real-estate on screen, which is not desired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter based on the `display` style property value.

```js
var $visible = $("#container div").filter(function() {
  return this.style.display !== 'none'
});

// or get style value using jQuery css() method
var $visible1 = $("#container div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('display') !== 'none'
});

console.log($visible.text())
console.log($visible1.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="display:none">
  <div>Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Hidden</div>
  <div>Another Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Another Hidden</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case the display property is set via inline style then you can use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)(not a perfect way, but in this case it would work).

```js
var $visible = $('#container div:not([style*="display:none"])');

console.log($visible.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="display:none">
  <div>Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Hidden</div>
  <div>Another Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Another Hidden</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent... I wasn't aware of the ability to pass a function to the `filter` method... this is just what I needed. Thanks :-)

Comment: @freefaller : you can use callback --- https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function

Answer (score 2):

Another option for your specific example would be to use the `:not()` selector.

```js
var els = $("#container div").filter(":not([style='display:none'])");

console.log(els.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="display:none">
  <div>Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Hidden</div>
  <div>Another Visible</div>
  <div style="display:none">Another Hidden</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

using style attribute and jquery not selector

```
$('#container :not([style="display:none"])')
```